# Downloading PDF's behind HTTPS with requests/BeautifullSoup wont work

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup, https, python-requests

I am trying to accomplish the following:
-Find all .PDF files on a webpage that requires a login
-Rename the .PDF files to only have the files name and not full URL
-Create a folder on the local users desktop
-Only download files that isn't already present in the created folder
-Download given .PDF files to the new folder

The code below logs into the website and retrieves all the .PDF files, slashes the name to be only the file name and downloads them to the folder. However all off the files seem to be corrupt(cant be opened)

Any kind of feedback or recommendations on how to fix it would be appreciated. (Payload has been altered as to not give any credentials away)

---

### Additional information:

---

Sampleurl is the main page of the website after logging in.
Loginurl is the page where users get authenticated
secure_url is the page containing all the .PDF's that i want to download

---

---

### Code:

```
# Import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from pprint import pprint
import time
import re
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.request

# Fetch username
username = os.getlogin()    

# Set folder location to local users desktop
folder_location = r'C:\Users\{0}\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices'.format(username)

Sampleurl = ('https://www.tict.io')
loginurl =('https://www.tict.io/auth/login')
secure_url = ('https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca')



payload = {
    'username': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxx',
    'ltfejs': 'xx'
    
}



  
with requests.session() as s:
    print("Connecting to website")
    s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    r = s.get(secure_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))


    print("Gathering .PDF files")
    # clean the pdf link names
    url_list = []
    for el in links:
        if(el['href'].startswith('https:')):
            url_list.append(el['href'])
        else:
            url_list.append(Sampleurl + el['href'])
    
    pprint(url_list)


    
    print("Downloading .PDF files")
        
    # download the pdfs to a specified location
    for url in url_list:
        print(url)
        fullfilename = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\{0}\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices'.format(username), url.split("/")[-1])
        if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)    
        print(fullfilename)
        request.urlretrieve(Sampleurl,fullfilename)

     
            
print("This program will automatically close in 5 seconds ")
time.sleep(5)
```

---

### Output

```
Connecting to website
Gathering .PDF files
['https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/quickscan.pdf',
 'https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/fullscan.pdf',
 'https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/improvementscan.pdf',
 'https://www.tict.io/downloads/privacylabel.pdf']
Downloading .PDF files
https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/quickscan.pdf
C:\Users\MATH\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices\quickscan.pdf
https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/fullscan.pdf
C:\Users\MATH\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices\fullscan.pdf
https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/improvementscan.pdf
C:\Users\MATH\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices\improvementscan.pdf
https://www.tict.io/downloads/privacylabel.pdf
C:\Users\MATH\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices\privacylabel.pdf
This program will automatically close in 5 seconds
```

It does download a working .PDF when manually clicking on one of the hyperlinks in the output.

---

### EDIT

I've adjusted my code and now it does download a working PDF to the allocated folder, however it only takes the last file in the list and wont repeat the cycle for the others

```
    print("Downloading .PDF files")
        
    # download the pdfs to a specified location
    for PDF in url_list:
        fullfilename = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\{0}\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices'.format(username), url.split("/")[-1])
        if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)    
        myfile = requests.get(PDF) 
        open(fullfilename, 'wb').write(myfile.content)
        

print("This program will automaticly close in 5 seconds ")
time.sleep(5)
```

Only privacylabel.pdf (last file in the **url_list**)
gets downloaded. The others wont appear in the folder.
When printing **PDF** it also only returns the privacylabel.pdf

Comment: Can you add ```print(myfile)``` in the PDF downloading code and see what Response is returned in every iteration?

Comment: It prints out: Myfile response: <Response [404]>
Myfile response: <Response [404]>
Myfile response: <Response [404]>
Myfile response: <Response [200]>  I suppose the 200response is for the privacylabel and the 404 are for all the other files. This might have something to do with the fact that the privacylabel on the secure_url is also available from the website before login.

Comment: Yes, that might be true.

Comment: I've also done a print(PDF) and in the download code and it returns valid hyperlinks which download the file when manually clicked on, so I have no idea why it still responds with 404 which would imply that the the file could not be found. Any suggestions on what I could  try?

Comment: You can try ```selenium```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Working

I forgot to call upon the session as s

```
myfile = requests.get(PDF)
```

should have been

```
myfile = s.get(PDF)
```

---

### Working code for those interested:

```
# Import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from pprint import pprint
import time
import re
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.request


# Fetch username
username = os.getlogin()    

# Set folder location to local users desktop
folder_location = r'C:\Users\{0}\desktop\Vodafone_Invoices'.format(username)

Sampleurl = ('https://www.tict.io')
loginurl =('https://www.tict.io/auth/login')
secure_url = ('https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca')


    

Username = input("Username: ")
Password = input("Password: ")

payload = {
    'username': (Username),
    'password': (Password),
    'ltfejs': 'xxx'
    
}

  
with requests.session() as s:
    print("Connecting to website")
    s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    r = s.get(secure_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))

    print("Gathering .PDF files")
    # clean the pdf link names
    url_list = []
    for el in links:
        if(el['href'].startswith('https:')):
            url_list.append(el['href'])
        else:
            url_list.append(Sampleurl + el['href'])
    
    pprint(url_list)

   
    
    print("Downloading .PDF files")
    
# download the pdfs to a specified location
    for url in url_list:
        fullfilename = os.path.join(folder_location, url.split("/")[-1])
        if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)    
        myfile = s.get(url)
        print(url)
        print("Myfile response:",myfile)
        open(fullfilename, 'wb').write(myfile.content)
                

print("This program will automaticly close in 5 seconds ")
time.sleep(5)
```

---

### Output

```
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx
Connecting to website
Gathering .PDF files
['https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/quickscan.pdf',
 'https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/fullscan.pdf',
 'https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/improvementscan.pdf',
 'https://www.tict.io/downloads/privacylabel.pdf']
Downloading .PDF files
https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/quickscan.pdf
Myfile response: <Response [200]>
https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/fullscan.pdf
Myfile response: <Response [200]>
https://www.tict.io/tool/87dd1218-f632-4ddb-b4d2-1f195bb4a5ca/improvementscan.pdf
Myfile response: <Response [200]>
https://www.tict.io/downloads/privacylabel.pdf
Myfile response: <Response [200]>
This program will automatically close in 5 seconds
```

---

### Conclusion

1. I had to call upon the session as s, since I forgot to do that the files could not be reached
2. I had to alter the download code a bit since the original tried downloading with urlretrieve and not requests